# Prove that $W = \{u = (x, y): y = 5x\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Interpret $W$ geometrically. What's the dimension of $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to learn how to do subspace proofs. Just want to see if I did the problems correctly. Thanks.

Let $u = (x, y), v = (z, w) \in W$

$u + v = (x, y) + (z, w) = (x + z, y + w) = (x + z, 5(x + z))$, so $u + v \in W.$

$cu = c(x, y) = c(x, 5x) = (cx, 5cx)$, so $cu \in W$.

Since $W$ is dependent, we have a line passing through the origin in $\mathbb R^2$. Its dimension is $1.$

Just to make sure I get what I am doing, I'll do another simple one:

> Prove that $W = \{(x, y, z): x = y = z\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Interpret $W$ geometrically. What's the dimension of $W$?

Let $u = (x, y, z), v = (a, b, c) \in W$.

$u + v = (x, y, z) + (a, b, c) = (x + a, y + b, z + c)$, so if $x = y = z = k$ for some $k$ and $a = b = c = s$ for some $s$, then $x + a = y + b = z + c = k + s$. Then $u + v \in W.$

$cu = (cx, cy, cz)$, so if $x = y = z = j$ for some $j$, then $cx = cy = cz = cj$ so that $cu \in W.$

Since $W$ is dependent, we have a line passing through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. Its dimension is $1.$

Comment: You are right. But in order to deal with the dimension I would give a basis explicitly. In the first case $\{(1,5)\}$ is a basis of $W$ since $$(x,y)\in W\implies (x,y)=(x,5x)=x(1,5).$$ I don't understand what you mean when saying "$W$ is independent".

Comment: This looks fine. Depending on who is teaching your course, they may be a little bit pedantic about showing explicitly that $0 \in W$. Also, be explicit about determining the dimension of a subspace. For example, you could write down a basis for $W$, and count the number of basis vectors. Because often it is not obvious what the dimension of a space is without doing some computations.

Comment: Ah, thanks. When I say $W$ is dependent, I mean the elements of $W$ are dependent.

Comment: To me that expression says nothing and as @ChristopherA.Wong says I would write down a basis explicitly. In the cases you are dealing with it may be obvious but for higher dimensions it could not be so easy. Good job and good luck.

Comment: @user306944, every vector space is a linearly dependent set.